# A weird rectangle is appearing when using bevel?

Tags: edges, bevel

[image]

[image]

I only wanted this:

[image]

But when I try to add a loop cut it does this.

[image]

Please help me make the triangle that appears out of no where not exist in my model. I just wanted to bevel this edge using the bevel modifier. Also note: I added that edge as a vertex group.

[image]

Comment: Hello make sure that you have no inner faces or overlapping vertices (select all and M > Merge by Distance), if it still doesn't work please share your file

Comment: And make sure you have no inverted normals by enabling _Face Orientation_ in the overlays, and maybe selecting all and pressing `Shift`+`N`to recalculate them.